# Flink timer async

Tags: asynchronous, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a question regarding Flink and its timer service.

I have a keyBy stream which uses a timer,
When the timer is called I need to send an http request which might take time to respond.
My question is, should I make the http call async?
or flink is making the timer call already as a new thread with async per key?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3):

You can use a `ProcessFunction` that stores the data required for the HTTP request, and that can have a timer. When it fires, you emit a record that has the request data, which a subsequent `AsyncFunction` will use to make the periodic request that you need.

Answer (score 1):

If You are asking if the `onTimer` method is invoked in a separate thread for each key, then I am pretty sure that it is not. So, You would need to invoke the HTTP call asynchronously in this case.

But to be completely honest, I don't think this is a good idea, in general, to use the `onTimer` function to perform HTTP calls. I don't know anything about Your use-case, but I think You should consider using different mechanisms like creating side-output and then using the Flink `Async` operator. Using asynchronous calls inside the `onTimer` can be tricky, especially if You consider things like retries, timeouts and possible failures.

So according to comment the use-case is to make a call to service each X mins and then post something to Kafka. So, what You could do is to simply have a process function that schedules timers. Each time the timer is fired You then generate some output record with data needed for request if there is any data needed. Then You use the `Async` operator to actually perform the requests, parse the response and based on the response generate some output record that can be then saved to Kafka.

Comment: Dominik is right, you should avoid doing any sort of blocking i/o in a Flink user function, such as a processElement or onTimer method. Doing so will prevent any progress from being made: no timers can fire for other keys, checkpoint barriers can not make progress, etc.

Comment: What I need to do is to make an http call to an external service every X mins to check for changes, and in case there is a change in the answer post something to kafka. I understand it should be async, but I couldn't think of another option other than timer.